# Loop for merging dictionaries with the same key

Tags: python, pandas, merge, vlookup, ordereddictionary

I have two excel files with two sheets each, which I have stored as dictionaries:

```
my_first_file = pd.read_excel(my_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)
my_second_file = pd.read_excel(my_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)
```

Ideally, I would like to write a loop that allows me to apply a *left merge* to the sheets with the same name.
So then I could filter the `NaN` values (just like a `vlookup` would do in Excel).

- my_first_file:

```
{'Sheet_1':     ID     Name  Surname  Grade
 0  104  Eleanor    Rigby      6
 1  168  Barbara      Ann      8
 2  450    Polly  Cracker      7
 3   90  Little       Joe     10,
 'Sheet_2':     ID       Name   Surname  Grade
 0  106       Lucy       Sky      8
 1  128    Delilah  Gonzalez      5
 2  100  Christina   Rodwell      3
 3   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7,
 'Sheet_3':     ID   Name   Surname  Grade
 0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9
 1   50  Grace     Kelly      7
 2  105    Uma   Thurman      7
 3   29   Lola      King      3}
```

- my_second_file:

```
{'Sheet_1':     ID     Name  Surname  Grade favourite color    favourite sport
 0  104  Eleanor    Rigby      6            blue  American football
 1  168  Barbara      Ann      8            pink             Hockey
 2  450    Polly  Cracker      7           black      Skateboarding
 3   90  Little      Josy     10          orange            Cycling,
 'Sheet_2':     ID       Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport
 0  106       Lucy       Sky      8          yellow          Tennis
 1  128    Delilah     Perez      5     light green      Basketball
 2  100  Christina   Rodwell      3           black       Badminton
 3   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7             red          Squash,
 'Sheet_3':     ID   Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport
 0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9           brown            Judo
 1   50  Grace     Kelly      7           white       Taekwondo
 2  105    Uma   Thurman      7          purple      videogames
 3   29   Lola   McQueen      3             red            Surf}
```

I am aware that `pd.df.merge(right, how='left', on='Concatenation')` is only appliable to DataFrames and not dictionaries like in this scenario but I have no clue on how to make it.
My **expected output** after merging the two dict keys for `Sheet_1` would be:

```
{'Sheet_1':     ID      Name  Surname  Contatenation  Grade favourite color  \
 0  104  Eleanor     Rigby  Eleanor Rigby      6            blue   
 1  168  Barbara       Ann    Barbara Ann      8            pink   
 2  450    Polly   Cracker  Polly Cracker      7           black   
 3   90   Little       Joe     Little Joe     10             NaN   
 
      favourite sport  
 0  American football  
 1             Hockey  
 2      Skateboarding  
 3                NaN  ,
```

I have proceded with this code so far:

```
# Importing modules
import openpyxl as op
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# Defining the two file paths
path_first_file = r'C:\Users\machukovich\Desktop\stack.xlsx'
path_second_file = r'C:\Users\machukovich\Desktop\stack_2.xlsx'

# Loading the files into a dictionary of Dataframes
dfs_first_file = pd.read_excel(path_first_file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)
dfs_second_file = pd.read_excel(path_second_file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Creating a new column in each sheet to merge later respectively
for sheet_name, df in dfs_first_file.items():
    df.insert(3, 'Concatenation', df['Name'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Surname'].map(str))

for sheet_name, df in dfs_second_file.items():
    df.insert(3, 'Concatenation', df['Name'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Surname'].map(str))
```

Thanks in advance for any tip and or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
sheets = dfs_first_file.keys() & dfs_second_file.keys() #common keys/sheets

dfs_output_file = {
    sh: pd.merge(dfs_first_file[sh],
                 dfs_second_file[sh],
        on=["Name", "Surname"], suffixes=("", "_"), how="left")
                .drop(columns=["ID_", "Grade_"]) for sh in sheets
}
```

*Explanation :*

Here we use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) inside a [*dictcomp*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) to overwrite the values (which are DataFrames) of the two dictionnaries (`dfs_first_file` *and* `dfs_second_file`). We overwrite them with the result of the left merge between the corresponding dataframes of the same sheet. For example, in the first iteration, `sh` equals `"Sheet1"`, so in this case we merge `dfs_first_file[sh]` with `dfs_second_file[sh]` (*while* `sh==Sheet1`).

Output :

```
print(dfs_output_file["Sheet_1"])

    ID     Name  Surname  Grade favourite color    favourite sport
0  104  Eleanor    Rigby      6            blue  American football
1  168  Barbara      Ann      8            pink             Hockey
2  450    Polly  Cracker      7           black      Skateboarding
3   90   Little      Joe     10             NaN                NaN

print(dfs_output_file["Sheet_2"])


    ID       Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport
0  106       Lucy       Sky      8          yellow          Tennis
1  128    Delilah  Gonzalez      5             NaN             NaN
2  100  Christina   Rodwell      3           black       Badminton
3   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7             red          Squash

print(dfs_output_file["Sheet_3"])

    ID   Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport
0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9           brown            Judo
1   50  Grace     Kelly      7           white       Taekwondo
2  105    Uma   Thurman      7          purple      videogames
3   29   Lola      King      3             NaN             NaN
```

Comment: You're welcome ;) I added a *brief explanation* of what's happening inside the dictcomp.

Comment: Hi merciful colleague, could you please substitute 'sh' for something more obvious so I could understand. By any chance could you let me know a loop to filter the NaN values on each sheet and print them out. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
out = {}
for k in dfs_first_file.keys() & dfs_second_file.keys():
    out[k] =  pd.merge(dct1[k], dct2[k], on=['ID', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Grade'])
    out[k]['Concatenation'] = out[k]['Name'] + ' ' + out[k]['Surname']

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Sheet_3':     ID   Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Concatenation
0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9           brown            Judo  Lucy Diamonds
1   50  Grace     Kelly      7           white       Taekwondo    Grace Kelly
2  105    Uma   Thurman      7          purple      videogames    Uma Thurman, 'Sheet_1':     ID     Name  Surname  Grade favourite color    favourite sport  Concatenation
0  104  Eleanor    Rigby      6            blue  American football  Eleanor Rigby
1  168  Barbara      Ann      8            pink             Hockey    Barbara Ann
2  450    Polly  Cracker      7           black      Skateboarding  Polly Cracker, 'Sheet_2':     ID       Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport      Concatenation
0  106       Lucy       Sky      8          yellow          Tennis           Lucy Sky
1  100  Christina   Rodwell      3           black       Badminton  Christina Rodwell
2   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7             red          Squash     Ziggy Stardust}
```